# JQUERY UI DatePicker Calendar not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working on JQuery UI Date Picker.

before it was working great but now the calendar won't show up.
any ideas?

here's my code.
http://pastebin.com/L4j2TmyY

my code is too long so i placed it in pastebin.

I follow this exactly but calendar is not showing
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: You are using datepick() 

the correct method is datepicker()

Comment: yes. I already changed that to datepicker() but still it doesn't show up.

Comment: Check the console (F12) and see what it is saying.

Comment: here's the screenshot of the console
http://postimg.org/image/3u1djes71/72f9ae28/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should download all the JavaScript files into your project folder and call the JavaScript files.

Example :

**Calling JavaScript from external URL (Not working)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>undelegate demo</title>
  <style>
  button {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  button#theone {
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="theone">Does nothing...</button>
<button id="bind">Bind Click</button>
<button id="unbind">Unbind Click</button>
<div style="display:none;">Click!</div>

<script>
function aClick() {
  $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
}
$( "#bind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .delegate( "#theone", "click", aClick )
    .find( "#theone" ).text( "Can Click!" );
});
$( "#unbind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .undelegate( "#theone", "click", aClick )
    .find( "#theone" ).text( "Does nothing..." );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Calling from project Folder(Working fine)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>undelegate demo</title>
  <style>
  button {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  button#theone {
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="theone">Does nothing...</button>
<button id="bind">Bind Click</button>
<button id="unbind">Unbind Click</button>
<div style="display:none;">Click!</div>

<script>
function aClick() {
  $( "div" ).show().fadeOut( "slow" );
}
$( "#bind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .delegate( "#theone", "click", aClick )
    .find( "#theone" ).text( "Can Click!" );
});
$( "#unbind" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .undelegate( "#theone", "click", aClick )
    .find( "#theone" ).text( "Does nothing..." );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As i saw your pastebin you are loading two jQuery libraries, which is not recommended, although you can use it with `jQuery.noConflict()`. So the quick fix is this:

Remove this library:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: this doesn't work either.. I've been working for this for almost 8hours now.. I cannot find where the error is.

Comment: @KimCarlo you can checkout any js error available in console of your browser.

Comment: here's the screenshot of the console

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwkoZTNT2pYwb0lUMGJ1dkZZUmM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

@Kim Carlo

I continue with @Rohit Bandooni's answer.

As his answer, it should work correctly.

A pastebin cloned from your paste: http://pastebin.com/2yNiXy44
I did some changes:
 - comment yours 2 "die" 
 - change the method name (search for text "CHANGE_BY_ME" in pastebin)

I run on my EasyPHP, it works well: http://imgur.com/kfmLkLY,lHsEUyv (2 images for 2 controls)
I found only 2 date controls on your page.